# Jquery smooth scrolling from seperate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery scrolling set up on my page, it scrolls beautifully with anchor tags on a single page. However when I i click a link and it changes pages and scrolls its not very smooth. Is there any way i can make it transition more smoothly? At the moment i am not using a plugin.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navi_bar">
    <li ><a class="fade-in" href="javascript: scrollto('about')">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a class="fade-in" href="javascript: scrollto('product')">some product</a></li>
    <li><a class="fade-in" href="javascript: scrollto('design')">some design</a></li>
    <li><a class="fade-in" href="join-us.html">JOIN US</a><li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

function scrollto(val) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+val).offset().top - $('#navi_bar').height()},700);
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you experience lag when you click on a link to change to another page, and within that page scrollTo(val) is called? In your code I see the scrollTo(val) only serve scrolling to anchor. Another thing, how is the lag, like does it spike when the page is scrolling (multiple times), or does it lag once and then scroll smoothly?

Comment: because on the home page i have 3 links in the navbar that are anchor tags that scroll nicely to other parts of the page. however if im away from the homepage and click the link it has a short lag and then scrolls down to the div(which is not very smooth in comparison if i stay on the homepage and scroll)

Comment: have a look for an example here

http://52.193.13.129/test_scroll/index.htm

Comment: @jsandrails scrolling is super smooth in Safari `9.0.1`

Comment: Ah, I my guess exactly then. It is a common behavior because of the loading time. When you see the top of the page, actually your entire page is not completely loaded yet. The browser was simply rendering the page from top down from the part of the data it has received. `$(document).ready()` waits until the DOM (the html) of the page is fully loaded before performing the function inside it. If you remove the $(document).ready() part and simply call the scrolling immediately, chance is high that the part you want to scroll to has not yet loaded.

Comment: I short my opinion is you'll have to accept it that way. I don't rule out possible solution though, but usually it will be pretty complicated and not worth the effort.

Comment: looking good on Chrome 47. could it be something about your computer or connection?

Comment: i think on the example i provided its not so bad, however on the page on my site has many large images(the hompage with slider). anyways thanks for the comments ill stick with this solution for now. @AvAvt

Comment: Wait that make it quite strange. `$(document).ready()` does *not* wait for images to be loaded. It only waits for html load. So by the time the function is called the browser already know there's an image there, but have not yet received the full data of the image yet. Possible flicker *during* the actual scrolling maybe because the browser didn't reserve space for the image, because it didn't know how large the image is. Quick fix is to give `width` and `height` **HTML** attribute to the img tags, so the browsers know how much space to reserve for it, eliminating flicker while scrolling.